# Serverless Framework Login From Behind a Proxy?

Tags: npm, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to use the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) from behind a proxy.

I was able to install the framework after configuring `npm` to use my certs file:

```
npm config set cafile C:\path\to\certs.pem

npm install serverless --global
```

However, when I try to login to serverless I get the following error:

```
serverless login
```

> > Fetch Error --------------------------------------------
> >
> > FetchError: request to https://api.serverless.com/core/tokens failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
> >           at ClientRequest. (D:\...\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\node-fetc
> >     h\index.js:133:11)

**How do I set the certs file to be able to login to serverless?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cafile` environment variable must be set before invoking `login`.  On windows powershell:

```
$env:cafile = "C:\path\to\certs.pem"
```

Comment: saved the day. Thanks.