# serverless deploy From Behind a Proxy?

Tags: npm, serverless-framework

**On a windows machine how do I run `serverless deploy` from behind a proxy using a cafile?**

I am [able to install serverless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758234/serverless-framework-login-from-behind-a-proxy) but when I run `serverless deploy` I get the following error:

> Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
>
> Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (unable to get local issuer certificate), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4

I have tried the following solutions, [suggested from this issue page](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4841), with no benefit:

- set environment variable `cafile` to a path containing my pem file
- set environment variable `ca` to the contents of my pem file
- set environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`
- `npm config set cafile = "/path/to/my/cert"`
- `npm config set strict-ssl = false`

Comment: I do it but I do not use a cafile. I do set my proxy in npm config though, like this `https-proxy = "http://proxy.acmexyz.com:8080/"
proxy = "http://proxy.acmexyz.com:8080/"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set default *nix proxy environment variables:

- http-proxy and
- https-proxy

in the form: http(s)://username:password@proxy.address:proxy_port.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Unfortunately it does not match my critieria, namely "using a cafile".

Answer (score 0):

If it is a secure proxy that you use, it might be the proxy `certificate` or `certificate's CA` that you need to  set as `cafile`.