# How to get serverless framework to use CA Cert

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

I'm on a corporate network. Said network requires a ca certificate for all encrypted transmissions.

I make this work using NPM by `npm config set cafile /path/to/cerrname.pem`

When I attempt to run `serverless` (or `sls` commands) commands of any kind I get

```
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)
```

This "unable to get local issuer certificate" is the exact same error I get if I don't set the CA file in npm.

How can I set the CA file in serverless framework?

I have looked at this answer ([Serverless Framework Login From Behind a Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758234/serverless-framework-login-from-behind-a-proxy)), which feels close, but when running the command in the accepted answer  and then trying to run `serverless` I get the same `unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's possible to address that by setting `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`, at least some users in the past were successful with that approach: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/9548#issuecomment-857882498